# Only in release build, clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/vagrant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I was building my project fine in debug mode, but started getting this error when I changed to Release

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/vagrant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-afhcainiqkrasrazkmlyzpkzbhne/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/skimitarDevelopment/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRNGoogleSignIn.a'

No entirely sure why, `libRNGoogleSignIn.a` is linked in my **Build Phases** on all of my targets.

This is first time I came across the issue, tried cleaning my project, deleting DerivedData folder, completely quitting (restarting) XCode with no luck.

`libRNGoogleSignIn.a` file mentioned in the error refers to this projects Product (https://github.com/Asimetriq/rn-google-sign-in/tree/master/ios)

It is added to my main project as a library i.e. I right click `Libraries` -> Add files to my project -> I select RNGoogleSignIn.xcodeproj

Afterwards I go to `Build Phases` and add `libRNGoogleSignIn.a` under Linking step.

I'm not sure if this is related, but file is highlighted in red:
[image]

And file is clearly linked, I'm not sure why it is never appearing in DerivedData

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is where the issue lies. My main project targets iOS 10.3, where as this library that was freshly created as cocoa touch static library was targeting ios 11+ by default.

As soon as I set libraries target to lower version i.e. 10 in my case it built correctly.

Comment: this helped, for the record be sure to set the right version for both the xcode project and the library target.  i.e.  click the gray colosseum icon, choose build settings, scroll down to the iOS Deployment Target setting (or search for it)

Comment: I try many times with this solution, What works for m I just build RNGoogleSignIn alone first successfully, then build the hole project

Answer (score 0):

The default **iOS Deployment Target** for RNGoogleSignin is **7.0**, change it to at least **8.0** should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be delete the Derived data directory and re-build